# Exclude files from precompile

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, webdeploy

I have Asp.Net MVC 5 application and I use `Precompile during publishing` option.

But I need for few .cshtml files to be excluded from precompilation. Is it possible to do?

Or if it isnt possible, can I somehow overwrite those few precompiled files with the original ones?

Answer (score 0):

I have never actually used this option before, but will be curious to hear if it works for your needs.  Right click on the View/Page you do not want to precompile and select Properties.  In the Properties window you should have several options. I am guessing if you select the following options seen highlighted in screenshot, it might accomplish what you are shooting for.

[image: Visual Studio Properties Window screenshot]

Comment: It didnt work. But I just renamed those .cshtml files to .html so they are not included in precompilation.